# Do not show collection number

Tags: symfony

I have a form "Survey" with a collection.

```
->add('comments', 'collection', array(
                        'type'         => new CommentType() ,
                        'allow_add'    => false,
                        'allow_delete' => false,
                        'label'        => false,
                    )
                )
```

My Form "CommentType" have only one field for entering comments:

```
$builder->add('comment', 'text', array('label'  => 'comment', 'translation_domain' => 'messages', 'attr' => array('maxlength' => 255)));
```

If i render my collection in twig template like this

```
{{ form_row(form.comments, {'attr': {}}) }}
```

Symfony/Twig always render a control label "control-label required" with a number for the rendered collection.

As example:

```
0 -> control-label required
Comment -> Label
[] -> Input field

1 -> control-label required
Comment -> Label
[] -> Input field
```

How can i disable this control label?

**Update**

[image: Show comment list with auto generated label]

Comment: what do you mean it creates control label? you have any picture or html?

Comment: @nawfal-serrar i add a image. The control-label was an additional item. I think that is generated automatically in collections, but I do'nt want it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `options` and `label` attributes for your collection, as follows

```
->add('comments', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new CommentType() ,
        'allow_add'    => false,
        'allow_delete' => false,
        'options'      => array(
                'label' => false,
        )
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you disabled the wrong label , leave the label of the collection and disable the one in your `->add('comment','text'.....)`